# Weird query string at the end of url posts in worspress

Tags: wordpress

This is a basic url format in my wordpress site:

mysite.com/lang/name-of-post/

or mysite.com/name-of-post/

The problem is that wordpress adds this query string at the end of the url:

## .WNzbB2f-uM8

So it becomes mysite.com/lang/name-of-post/#.WNzbB2f-uM8

How to remove this query string?

Answer (score 0):

1- first go to settings / permalinks menu and see it's option for this string .
2- second change your active theme with default wordpress theme like 2016 and check url.
3- third disable all plugin and see your site urls for this string

i thinks you can find the problem with above suggestions

Comment: 1. There's no option for this string here.  2. Activated another theme (default) and it worked 3, No results here;  But now I want to have my theme and no query string.

Comment: please contact your theme developer